# a way to combine/merge objects in json

Tags: jquery, json, merge

I have this inconvenient output of data, like this:

```
[
    {
        "object_a": {
            "1": "some value of 1",
            "2": "some value of 2",
            "3": ""
        },
        "obejct_b": {
            "1": "",
            "2": "",
            "3": "some value of 3"
        },
        ..some other objects..
    }
    {
        "object_a": {
            "1": "some value of 1",
            "2": "",
            "3": "some value of 3"
    },
        "obejct_b": {
            "1": "",
            "2": "some value of 2",
            "3": ""
        },
        ..some other objects..
    }
    {
        "object_a": {
            "1": "",
            "2": "some value of 2",
            "3": ""
        },
        "obejct_b": {
            "3": "some value of 3",
            "1": "some value of 1",
            "2": ""
        },
        ..some other objects..
    }
]
```

I don't know what more to add. It looks straightforward as it is.
Unfortunately, I cannot change the output format.
The problem is that some data is in "object_a" and some in "object_b"

The desired output would be like:

```
[
    {
        "object": {
            "1": "some value of 1",
            "2": "some value of 2",
            "3": "some value of 3"
        }
        ..some other objects..
    }
    {
        "object": {
            "1": "some value of 1",
            "2": "some value of 2",
            "3": "some value of 3"
        },
        ..some other objects..
    }
        {
        "object": {
            "2": "some value of 2",
            "3": "some value of 3",
            "1": "some value of 1",
        },
        ..some other objects..
    }
]
```

I couldn't find a way to combine/merge two objects together, with jQuery.

Thanks.

Comment: `newObject = { ...object1, ...object2 }`? With the caveat that if you have duplicate keys the last key wins. It's not super-clear what you're asking or how jQuery is involved--this is just JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some assumptions must be made:

- Every object in the top-level array will have the same two (and only these two) properties `object_a` and `obejct_b` [sic].
- Every `object_a` and `obejct_b` will have the same set of properties.
- For any key in an `object_a` that is an empty string, the value in the "merged" result should be that of the corresponding `obejct_b`.

With these assumptions, I would use the following code.
(Note that I have left as is the typo in `obejct_b`.)

```js
const output = [
  {
    "object_a": {
      "1": "some value of 1",
      "2": "some value of 2",
      "3": ""
    },
    "obejct_b": {
      "1": "",
      "2": "",
      "3": "some value of 3"
    },
    "some other object": {
      "foo" : "bar"
    }
  },
  {
    "object_a": {
      "1": "some value of 1",
      "2": "",
      "3": "some value of 3"
    },
    "obejct_b": {
      "1": "",
      "2": "some value of 2",
      "3": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "object_a": {
      "1": "",
      "2": "some value of 2",
      "3": ""
    },
    "obejct_b": {
      "3": "some value of 3",
      "1": "some value of 1",
      "2": ""
    }
  }
];

const merged = output.map(item => {
  // assumes object_a and obejct_b have the same keys
   const mergedAB =  Object.keys(item.object_a).reduce((acc, key) => {
    // assuming typo in "obejct_b" is intentional
    acc[key] = item.object_a[key] || item.obejct_b[key];
    return acc;
  }, {});
  
  const others = { ...item };
  delete others.object_a;
  delete others.obejct_b;
  
  return {
    object: mergedAB,
    ...others
  }
});

document.body.innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(merged, null, 2)}</pre>`;
```